# R Confusion Matrix using sum

Tags: r, confusion-matrix

I have a data table with an actual and a predicted value. I can generate a confusion matrix easily enough, but I would like each element of the matrix to be a sum of a third column. In the example code below, you can think of each row of the data table as a polygon that has an actual and a predicted land classification and an associated area. I would like the confusion matrix to show the sum of areas in each pairing.

```
library(data.table)
library(caret)

set.seed(9)

# Possible land classifications
land.class <- c("Grass","Building","Road","Parking")

# Build a data table of actual and predicted values
dt <- data.table(actual=sample(land.class,100,replace=TRUE),
             predict=sample(land.class,100,replace=TRUE),
             area=rnorm(n=100,mean=50,sd=15))

# Confusion matrix
confusionMatrix(dt$predict,dt$actual)

# Which is the same as
table(dt$predict,dt$actual)

# How do I get each cell to be the sum of the area?
sum(dt[actual=='Grass' & predict=='Grass']$area)
sum(dt[actual=='Grass' & predict=='Building']$area)
```

Comment: I don't think a confusion matrix can do what you're describing, but try `aggregate(area ~ actual + predict, data=dt, sum)`, maybe that will work

Comment: or in a more tabular form, `library(reshape2); dcast(dt, actual ~ predict, fun.aggregate=sum)`